# ajax pagination - Can't get last table row

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

This code works perfectlly. But I can't get last row of the table. 
ex: My table had 9 rows but this displying only 8 rows, 1 row missing. Missing row is the last row when I use ASC or DESC.
here's my code.. **sorry my English not good.**
thank you!

index.php

```
<?php
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'ad_man';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$item_per_page = 2;
$connecDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('could not connect to database');
    if($check_ad = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT ad_uid FROM fullbanner WHERE ad_uid='501'")){
        $countr=mysqli_num_rows($check_ad);
    if($countr>=1){

    $pages = $countr/$item_per_page;


    //create pagination
    if($pages > 1)
    {
        $pagination = '';
        $pagination .= '<ul class="paginate">';
        for($i = 1; $i<$pages; $i++)
        {
            $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }
        $pagination .= '</ul>';
    }

    }else {$pagination="<ul class='paginate'>Empty ADs</ul>";}}else {$pagination="Empty ADs";}//mama
    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Ajax Pagination</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load

        $(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {

            $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');

            var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
            var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need 

            $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class

            //post page number and load returned data into result element
            //notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
            $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':(page_num-0)}, function(){

            });

            $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to currently clicked element (style purpose)

            return false; //prevent going to herf link
        }); 
    });
    </script>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <?php echo $pagination; ?>          
    </body>
    </html>
```

fetch_pages.php

```
<?php

include("config.inc.php"); //include config file

//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//validate page number is really numaric
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');}

//get current starting point of records
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

//Limit our results within a specified range. 
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM fullbanner WHERE ad_uid='501' ORDER BY ad_count ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");

//output results from database
echo '<ul class="page_result">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    echo '<li id="item_'.$row["ad_count"].'">'.$row["ad_code"].'. <span class="page_name">'.$row["ad_title"].'</span><span class="page_message"><a href="../new/image_ads/'.$row["image_url"].'" target="_new"><< Viwe AD image >></a></span></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

thank you!

Comment: What is the value of $position used with LIMIT in fetch_pages.php ?

Comment: `$position = ($_POST["page"] * $item_per_page);` Last page number @Deepak

Comment: Just do echo $position and see the value.

Comment: 1st page = 0 | 2nd = 4 | 3rd = 6 | 4th - 8 ... start with 0 but when I click 1st page it echo 2 @Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the page number is equal to 0, if not simply divide $position by 2

```
//get current starting point of records
if ($position === 0) $position = $position;
else $position = ($position/2)
```

This worked for me